# Show different Menu items if user is logged or not

Tags: reactjs, authentication, menu, react-admin

In my React-Admin app I want to be able to have pages that are only available to logged users and others to not logged users. And this needs to be shown in Menu too. If user is not logged there should only be visible in `<Menu>` pages that do not require authentication, but if he initiates session, pages that require authentication and those which don't should be visible in `<Menu>`.

I've used `<Authenticated>`component in `<Menu>` for that but this redirects me to Login page if user is not authenticated and I don't want that. I want to have a set of custom pages including a home page which are available to all users and the `<Resources>` only available and reachable to authenticated ones.

```
const Menu = ({resources, onMenuClick, logout, hasDashboard, translate, ...props}) =>{

 return <div>
   {hasDashboard && <DashboardMenuItem onClick={onMenuClick} translate={translate}/>}
   <MenuItemLink
     to="/toAllUsersPage"
     primaryText={translate('toAllUsersPage.title')}
     leftIcon={<MapIcon />}
     onClick={onMenuClick}
   />

   <Authenticated location={props.location}>
     <div>
       {resources.map(resource => (
         <MenuItemLink
           key={resource.name}
           to={`/${resource.name}`}
           primaryText={translate(`resources.${resource.name}.name`, { smart_count: 2 })}
           onClick={onMenuClick}
           leftIcon={ resource.icon ? <resource.icon /> : <DefaultIcon /> }
         />
       ))}
     </div>
   </Authenticated>

   <MenuItemLink
     to="/login"
     primaryText={translate('login.name')}
     leftIcon={<LoginIcon />}        
     onClick={onMenuClick}
   />       
 </div>

}
```

As was previously said this solution always redirects to Login Page, even if I try the URL to a page that should be available because `AUTH_CHECK` fails in authProvider in `Authenticated` component. And I can't a have `<LoginButton>` since `Authenticated` only render if authProvider promise resolves. I was previously using `isLoggedIn` in redux state but that only says if last `AUTH_CHECK` resolves successfully giving inconsistencies at page refresh.

With this in mind is possible for `Authenticated` not redirect to Login page or redirect to a page of my choosing and/or can I have a LoginButton in Menu only visible when user is not logged?

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use the `isLoggedIn` prop directly ?

```
const Menu = ({resources, onMenuClick, logout, hasDashboard, translate, isLoggedIn, ...props}) => (
    <div>
        {hasDashboard && <DashboardMenuItem onClick={onMenuClick} translate={translate}/>}

        <MenuItemLink
            to="/toAllUsersPage"
            primaryText={translate('toAllUsersPage.title')}
            leftIcon={<MapIcon />}
            onClick={onMenuClick}
        />

        {isLoggedIn && resources.map(resource => (
            <MenuItemLink
                key={resource.name}
                to={`/${resource.name}`}
                primaryText={translate(`resources.${resource.name}.name`, { smart_count: 2 })}
                onClick={onMenuClick}
                leftIcon={ resource.icon ? <resource.icon /> : <DefaultIcon /> }
            />
        ))}

        <MenuItemLink
            to="/login"
            primaryText={translate('login.name')}
            leftIcon={<LoginIcon />}
            onClick={onMenuClick}
        />
    </div>
);
```

Comment: isLoggedIn prop comes from listening to isLoggedIn in redux state which tells last result of USER_CHECK, not if user is logged or not, and defaults to false. I forgot to delete that from example code, already edited.

Comment: USER_CHECK is used to know if the user is logged in so I don't see the prb using it. Can you explain ?

Comment: My bad isLoggedIn in redux state tells the result of last AUTH_CHECK, not USER_CHECK, as said in a [issue](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/1967) I opened a few days ago. As far as I know there isn't any variable that tells if user is logged or not. The solutions that resolve my problem can be a variable that tells logged state of user, or a way that <Authenticated> doesn't redirects to LoginPage and continues program execution.  

PS: I'm using menu prop of <Admin> in RA version 2.0, I just saw that it become deprecated. Will a custom Layout fix this problem?

Comment: Yeah, I meant `AUTH_CHECK` too. It does reflect the fact that the user is authorized to access the app, hence logged in. So I still don't see the issue with using `isLoggedIn`. The custom layout won't solve the problem

Comment: The issue is that if the page is refreshed, redux state resets, `isLoggedIn` goes back to default and an `AUTH_CHECK` is **not** performed on initiation. Meaning that after refresh Menu will assume user is **not** logged but it is.

Comment: I see. You'll have to implement a custom reducer then. How are you checking whether a user is logged in ? sessionStorage ?

Comment: I'm not using any custom reducer with `isLoggedIn` that variable comes from RA redux state. However a custom authProvider is being used and in `AUTH_CHECK` the existence of a token in **localStorage**, for developing purposes, defines if user is logged in,

Comment: Ok I see the issue now, I'll work on another answer asap

Comment: Do you have an approximate date where it will be possible answering?

Comment: Sorry no. Very busy right now. In a nutshell, declare a custom reducer for your own isLoggedIn state, which will initialize its state from your localStorage (you really should use sessionStorage btw, more secure) and listen the USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS and USER_LOGOUT actions

Comment: Got it. I fixed the problem with a custom saga that listens for `USER_CHECK` and calls `authProvider` with `AUTH_CHECK` and if successful does `USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS`. It works but it will this on every CHECK even when user is loggedIn, yours makes more sense. Either way, since different views can be shown depending on user authentication, shouldn't RA check if user is logged in before rendering?

Comment: There are so many ways to define if a user is logged in or not. We'd rather give you the responsibility to do that. Besides, some app do not even need authentication ;)